# Facebook post display on user's wall and page

Tags: php, facebook

Is it possible with the PHP SDK to post something to a user's wall, and display the same post on a fan-page as well, so if someone comments on it, it can be visible on both places?

I can manage to post with my app separately, but it would be great to mirror the posts.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Rufinus, could you explain it to me how? If you need more information from me, please let me know.

Comment: I guess you would have to “share” the user’s wall post on the page for this to work. Alas, that functionality is only available for photos or links a user posted, not for “normal” posts containing none of these.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add both function in one function to post it.

or you can set option to post one place or both in buttons.

as you said u can post them separately,, then why dont add both function together.

cheers

Comment: i think with "on a page" he meant a website, not a facebook fan-page

Comment: Thanks for your help Deepak. Could you be a little bit more specific, how can I put the two functions together? I am using php sdk as I said.